Circuit training with usual break times - a good idea?
Short: Is it better to train each exercise in a row or should we rather do a "circuit training" with same exercises and same break lengths?

Let's say we have a full body workout with pull, push and legs exercises. For example, we could say that the session consists of push ups, pull ups and squats. Further, we choose 3 sets done till failure and a break time of one minute between sets.
With this key points in mind I usually would start with exercise A, do first set, pause, second set, pause and finally the third set. After some break I would do the same with exercise B and C.
But I wonder whether it is a good idea to implement some kind of circuit training instead. What I mean is that one can do first set of exercise A, pause one minute, go on with first set of exercise B, pause one minute, do first set of exercise C, pause one minute, then doing the same for set two and three.
So with this method in the end we would have done three sets of the three exercises with 8 breaks in total - just like if we did the exercises in a row! But the advantage of this method should be that we have three minutes break before we do the same exercise again (the break being even longer for a workout with more than three exercises). Accordingly, we should recover better from the former set of the same exercise. Hence we should be able to reach higher reps in set two and further compared to doing the same exercise in a row. The volume of such a workout would be higher, leading to better gains. For example, I can do more pull ups after 'one minute break/ push ups/ one minute break/ squats/ one minute break' than if I do another set of pull ups one minute after I just did a set of pull ups.
The advantages seem pretty obvious and therefore I am surprised that most content I read and see don't recommend this regime. Why is this the case? Am I missing something? All I can think of is that when talking about circuit training it is usually said that breaks are really short or there even is no break at all. The method I describe on the other hand uses same break times as if one would do exercises in a row.

This is not particularly uncommon. The major disadvantage is that where the exercises performed require equipment, that equipment must be monopolised for much longer than if the same exercises were performed in sequence, and this is typically frowned upon in gyms.
Additional drawbacks include:

For beginners, doing one exercise at a time lets them focus on learning the movement, rather than having to remember what technical aspect of each lift they needed to focus on from the previous set, while having done multiple other exercises since then.
When this technique is applied as a time saving measure (by reducing rest times between sets of different exercises), the session becomes more systemically taxing, and thus harder.
Muscle fatigue is a goal in hypertrophy training, and so reducing fatigue by effectively having much longer rest periods in order to get more reps in during the later sets is not considered beneficial. (Though it is beneficial for strength training.)


Is there a source which empirically shows that more reps with less fatigue are bad for hypertrophy but good for strength? That point is really interesting.

It's not that eliminating between-sets fatigue is detrimental to hypertrophy, more that it isn't necessary. Hypertrophy tends to be similar with short rest periods compared to long ones, whereas strength outcomes tend to do better with longer rest periods. Compare DOI 10.1080/17461391.2017.1340524 to DOI 10.1007/s40279-017-0788-x

Weirdly there are some studies showing that the one minute rest time recommendation for hypertrophy is wrong and one should rest long, as summerized here with nine references. Therefore to mine understanding longer rests are good for strength and muscle growth.

That video just seems to be grossly misrepresenting the research in order to push a specific narrative.

Did you have a look in the sources? I have just access at work, so not now. But already the abstract of the review says for example that "Novel findings involving trained participants using measures sensitive to detect changes in muscle hypertrophy suggest a possible advantage for the use of long rest intervals to elicit hypertrophic effects" - just as stated in the video

I wouldn't ever bother looking at sources that are merely presented as a "references" list without individual claims attached to them. But the systematic review he cites during the video was the same one that I linked in my comment above, and the video's claim that it found that longer rest was best is a lie. The paper actually concluded "due to the paucity of studies with similar designs, further research is needed to provide a clear differentiation between [long and short rest periods]".

You cite the part where they write that further research is needed, but that is just some standard phrase. The conclusion of the review is that "Novel findings involving trained participants using measures sensitive to detect changes in muscle hypertrophy suggest a possible advantage for the use of long rest intervals to elicit hypertrophic effects". It's awkward to cite the standard phrase instead because it is included in pretty much every paper. It least I never encountered a paper saying"No further research is needed"

"Possible" means "it might have been there, but this study failed to demonstrate it". You don't see the "further research is needed" when a systematic review demonstrates a positive outcome.

The full-text of the paper also explicitly stated that the calculated difference between short and long rest outcomes was not significant.

Now I see what you mean(t). You don't see the "further research is needed" when a systematic review demonstrates a positive outcome -> it depends.. Even in a review/ meta analysis with an significant effect there might be some limitations so that further research is needed. But this is another topic. Thanks!
